# Reduce the runtime of a query which parses 5 TB of data

Tags: python, google-bigquery

`Use case`  : A single query creates a table having 6000 columns and 93Million records.

`Issue` : This query mostly fails with resources exceed issue.

`Try No 1` : As a part of optimization I break down the query to multiple subtasks to run in parallel(Using some python code and clustering column). Even after doing so the query takes `20-25 mins`  to finish.

[image]

Explaination : here first task create  a query using CTAS `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <tbl1> cluster by col1  AS  SELECT * FROM <tbl2> WHERE col1 BETWEEN 1 and 2`

Rest other tasks are `INSERT INTO TABLE <tbl1> SELECT * FROM <tbl2> WHERE col1 BETWEEN 3 and 30` .
Note - The col1(clustering column) values keeps on changing for each task.

`Try No 2` : I am seeing links around running queries asynchronously. Will it be helpful here in this case where I am already dividing the query in multiple subtasks?

Any help is appreciated for optimizing the run time.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the query or knowing what it does. Also, 20 minutes for 50 terabytes doesn't sound... too bad?

Comment: Its a just a single CTAS query

Comment: Also, the data is not 50 TB , its 5 TB.  I have updated it now.

Comment: Instead of `insert` create a table (from `tbl1_0001` to`tbl_0999`) for each run.  At the end:
`CREATE TABLE  tbl1 cluster by col1 as Select * from tbl1_*`

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for the quick response. I would like to know this way I will creating 30 temporary tables(as I have 30 subtasks) and finally I will be inserting all data again into final permanent table which will parse all the 30 temporary tables in one go.  How is that different in terms of `INSERT` query where I am inserting a portion of data (each subtask) to final table. Is there a catch how internally these 2 approaches differ

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns  The INSERT DML statement is intended to be used sparingly.